# HTML/Angular2 - how to speed up the drawing of multiple select boxes?

Tags: html, performance, angular

Ive a form that displays 20 select boxes, very slowly.  They each just have a 0 to 4 value in them so no huge lists.  But when the form loops through this you just sit there watching them draw one by one. Ok it only takes a second or so but its annoying. Is there any way of speeding things up a bit?  if it was a desktop app you could make the section invisible, draw it and then make it visible again which makes things quick.  Can i do anything like that with a web page?

This is the loop that draws it all, "rating" being the child component which is just a select box.

```
        <tr *ngFor="let name of measureNames">
            <td class="col-sm-1">{{name.measure}}</td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let rating of ratings | groupFilter: name.measureID">
                <ng-container *ngFor="let key of rating | keys">
                    <td name="ratingCell" class="col-sm-1" *ngIf="key=='ratingID'"><rating #singleRating (ratingChanged)="onRatingChange($event)" name="{{rating.measureID}}/{{rating.timePeriodID}}" [ratingID]="rating.ratingID" [selectedRating]="rating[key]"></rating></td>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </tr>
```